# How to add terms directly from the content overview?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I have a few taxonomies with custom fields. I would like the user to be able to add terms directly from the content overview page at `admin/content`, and for the terms to be listed there - without having to navigate to the taxonomies page. As if the taxonomies were a content type. Any suggestions?

Comment: d7 or d8? Do you mean add terms right from the `admin/structure/taxonomy` page or `admin/content`?

Comment: from admin/content under D8

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form).